# Neo4j : How to combine multiple cyphers into one?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4j DB with usual social graph. I'm trying to create an activity feed (User X followed you, User Y liked your Message etc.)

There are `User` and `Message` Nodes.

And `Follows`, `Likes` and `Mentions` relationships, each with a `created_on` property.

(there are actually a few more relationships I want, but for brevity I've kept it to 3 for the example)

I'm trying to return a list of Activity events, paginated and ordered by date. Each Activity would have the date it happened, the user it relates to and the message if applicable.

I have this working for each Activity type/relationship, but I am struggling to get them all combined into one cypher / response.

The Cyphers individually are...

**Likes**

```
MATCH (me:User {username:"matt"})-[:Owner]->(msg:Message)<-[likes:Likes]-(user:User) RETURN user, msg, likes.created_on ORDER BY likes.created_on LIMIT 25
```

**Mentions**

```
MATCH (me:User {username:"matt"})<-[mentions:Mentions]-(msg:Message)-[:Owner]-(user:User) RETURN user, msg, mentions.created_on ORDER BY mentions.created_on LIMIT 25
```

**Follows**

```
MATCH (me:User {username:"Matt"})<-[follows:Follows]-(user:User) RETURN user, follows.created_on ORDER BY follows.created_on LIMIT 25
```

I initially combined them all with `optional` but this returns more then one result / relationship type per row.  So one Activity could have both a `comment` and a `mention`. This would then mess up the limit request, as we have 2 activities taking up one result.

So then I tried `WHERE` and `OR`

```
 MATCH (me:User {username:"Matt"})-[r]-(m)--(u)
    WHERE me-[:Owner]->(m:Message)<-[r:Likes]-(u:User)
    OR me<-[r:Message]-(m:Message)-[:Owner]-(u:User)
    OR me<-[r:Follows]-(u:User)
    RETURN m, u, r.created_on
    ORDER BY r.created_on
    LIMIT 25
```

But I'm getting quite lost now! This appears to return no results at all

Any advice / pointer on how to combine the above Cyphers into one request?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
MATCH (me:User {username:"matt"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)-[:Owner]->(msg:Message)<-[likes:Likes]-(user:User) 
WHERE likes.created_on > x-days-ago
WITH me, msg, user, likes.created_on as created_on
ORDER BY created_on LIMIT 25
WITH me, collect(distinct {user:user, created_on:created_on}) as activities
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)<-[mentions:Mentions]-(msg:Message)-[:Owner]->(user:User) 
WITH me, msg, user, mentions.created_on as created_on, activities
ORDER BY created_on LIMIT 25
WITH me, activities + collect(distinct {user:user, created_on:created_on}) as activities
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)<-[follows:Follows]-(user:User) 
WITH me, msg, user, follows.created_on as created_on, activities
ORDER BY created_on LIMIT 25
UNWIND (activities + collect(distinct {user:user, created_on:created_on})) as activity
RETURN activity
ORDER BY activity.created_on LIMIT 25
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use union http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-union.html
This way you get all the results

Comment: Thanks, I have the UNION approach working, however the Limit and Order  are applied to each query, not the overall query.  Apparently applying an overall limit to UNION queries is not yet supported (https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/2725)   So close, but so far...

Comment: maybe ask neo4j that they will implement it. Or do it in code afterwards